# AsynTask Determine When Finished

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I'm wanting to return a Boolean value from a method which calls an AsyncTask to execute if order to find if it's finished. previously I called the .get() method (which was fine) but this halts all threads and I would like a progress dialog.

I'm toying with the idea of a for loop which sleep/waits say every 100ms and then checks getStatus() to see if it's equal to Status.FINISHED, but this seems like a poor idea.

Below is a small portion of code.

> ```
>   jData.theTask.execute(url);
>
>
>   if(jData.theTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
>       if(!WebService.webServiceValid()) {
>              showMessage();
>              return false;
>          }
>
>       return true;
>   }
>
>
>   Log.d("fired", "false fired");
>   return false;
> ```

The operation isn't going to be instantly complete, so it's just returning false and a race condition is occurring due to the operation has not finished. As mention above I could wrap it in a for loop to periodically check x amount of times, but I'm sure there's probably a better solution out there.

Many thanks

EDIT:

It seems that calling .execute() then .get() actually allows the UI to spawn my progress dialog box whilst waiting for the boolean from .get(long timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit). This is a solution to my problem, however I'll leave the question open until tomorrow incase anyone has comments regarding this.

Comment: It is a very bad practice to use AsyncTask.get(). You actually sacrifice the benefits of AsyncTask and make UI thread blocked and  waiting for worker thread, hence not Asynchronous anymore. What even worse is app may throws ApplicationNotRespondingException. You should restructure you code and implement what you need all inside onPostExecute() callback method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most appropriate place to know if a AsyncTask was completed is the method `onPostExecute` which is called after the `doInBackground()` execution. What you can do is return a `Boolean` variable from `doInBackground()` based on the execution of your background activity. When the control reaches `onPostExecute()` you can be assured that your background activity has completed.

The manner in which you are using the `AsyncTask` is inappropriate because after the call to `execute()` on a `AsyncTask` object the control returns to the next line of code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yeah I'm using OnPostExecute() to close my ProgressDialog and I'm returning a Boolean too, it's just the checking of completion from the actual Async object. I could call .execute() then .get() for a boolean, but then the caller thread gets still gets blocked so no dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Move the contents of if(jData.theTask.getStatus()==AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {} block to inside onPostExecute()